# How to send request to bank and receive response using ISO 8583 messages?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment-processing, iso8583, payment-services

I have a question about ISO 8583 messages. I learned my self how to create an ISO 8583 massage but I don't know how to use this message to send request and receive response from the bank. 
In which way can I get connect with the bank? And how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make connection between bank and payment terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877953/how-to-make-connection-between-bank-and-payment-terminal)

Answer (score 3):

There are different types of connections.

For sample it could be secure TCP/IP socket connection, permanent or connection on demand.

It can be HTTPS messages exchange where HTTP headers play one of primary role with data routing and customer identification.

Also iso8583 message can be extended with different message headers or length identifiers.

Some protocols used blocks exchange splitting the iso8583 message to small parts. It is limitation of old infrastructure used behind.

So, you should clarify the connection method with your acquirer bank or service provider. If you authorized developer for that services you should get this info without problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help, how to use TCP/IP socket connection? And from where can I get bank ip or host?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a network socket on the host and send the message through as a byte array.

You could use most programming languages to do this, but [here is an example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx) of sending a byte array to a network socket it in C#. (Populate the `bytesSent` variable with your ISO message.)

Comment: Thank you for your help, how to use network socket connection? And from where can I get bank ip or host? And how to do a test?

Comment: You need to ask these questions separately in different topics.

Comment: @iso8583.infosupport can you answer me here http://stackoverflow.com/q/40877953/6335333